# Flexbox puts image at top but text-links at bottom

Tags: html, css, image, flexbox

I got a project where I put a flex menu on top of a picture slider. I want the items to use the same baseline, but I cannot set it to be on the same line.

```css
a img{
  height: 40px;
}
.links{
  display: flex;
  align-items: baseline;
}
```

```html
<div class="links">
  <a class="img-link"> <img src="anypicture.jpg"></a>
  <a>Link 1</a>
  <a>Link 2</a>
  <a>Link 3</a>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/7xnesjpy/13/

The container of the picture is slightly above the container of the text-links, what can I do to set them to the same ground/baseline

Comment: because you've told it to?  The problem is your image has the white-space at the bottom

Comment: The image used in your fiddle, https://www.zdf.de/assets/logo-logo-schwarz-100~760x340?cb=1516364243305, has lots of transparent space underneath the orange logo ... add `background-color: blue` for the img element, then you will see that it already is aligned on the baseline, same as the text.

Comment: Okay, then this is a bad example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use `baseline`, it is the `img`'s bottom that will line up with the bottom of the text, as you can see here, where I added a border to the items.

```css
a img{
  height: 40px;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}
.links{
  display: flex;
  align-items: baseline;
}
.links a + a {
  border: 1px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="links">
  <a class="img-link"> <img src="https://staticaltmetric.s3.amazonaws.com/uploads/2015/10/dark-logo-for-site.png"></a>
  <a>Link 1</a>
  <a>Link 2</a>
  <a>Link 3</a>
</div>
```

---

For the `img` to align with the text/link elements bottom, you need `flex-end`.

```css
a img{
  height: 40px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
.links{
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-end;
}
.links a {
  border: 1px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="links">
  <a class="img-link"> <img src="https://staticaltmetric.s3.amazonaws.com/uploads/2015/10/dark-logo-for-site.png"></a>
  <a>Link 1</a>
  <a>Link 2</a>
  <a>Link 3</a>
</div>
```

---

But as you can see in the 2nd sample, there is still a *gap* below the `img`.

This [*gap* all inline element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5078239/how-do-i-remove-the-space-between-inline-block-elements) has, and to get rid of that, change the `img`'s display type to `block`.

```css
a img{
  display: block;
  height: 40px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
.links{
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-end;
}
.links a + a {
  border: 1px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="links">
  <a class="img-link"> <img src="https://staticaltmetric.s3.amazonaws.com/uploads/2015/10/dark-logo-for-site.png"></a>
  <a>Link 1</a>
  <a>Link 2</a>
  <a>Link 3</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your image has a lot of transparent space around it, but you can fix it by adding 
margin to you a img{} like so:

```
a img{
  height: 40px;
  margin-bottom:-20px;
}

.links{
  display: flex;
  align-items: baseline;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your CSS is working fine but the problem is the image. There is unwanted space in your image. Please see in the fiddle now.

Comment: I updated the image, the container is still slightly above the others

Answer (score 0):

Removing all Padding and Margin from the image fixes it.

```
a img {margin: 0; padding: 0;}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/7xnesjpy/27/